# Counting the intersection of equivalent rows in two tables

Tags: python

I have two FITS files. Let us consider **for example the first file has 100 rows and 2 columns. The second file has 1000 rows and 2 columns.**

```
    FITS FILE 1      FITS FILE 2

    A        B        C        D
    1        2        1        2
    1        3        1        2  
    2        4        1        2
```

I need to take the **first row of the first file, i.e 1 and 2 and check how many rows in the second file have 1 and 2.** In our example, **we have 3 rows in the second file that have 1 and 2.**  I need to do the same for the second row (first file), i.e 1 and 3 and find out how many rows in the second file have 1 and 3 and so on.

**The first file does not have duplicates (all the rows have different pairs, none are identical, only file 2 has many identical pairs which I need to find).**

**I finally need the numbers of rows in the second file that have the similar values as that of the rows of the first FITS file.**

So finally it will be:

```
A    B    Number
1    2      3   # 1 and 2 occurs 3 times
1    3      5   # 1 and 3 occurs 5 times
```

and so on.

I know I somehow need to iterate through the list and get the answer. I know `zip` will get me the rows of the first file, but I am not finding a way to iterate with these values.

What I have been trying to do so far is somehow achieve it using `zip`:

```
for i,j in zip(A,B):
    for m,n in zip(C,D):
```

By using `for i,j in zip(A,B):` I get `i,j` to be the first row of my first file and so on. So I can compare it with the second file.

Comment: FYI I suggested an edit to change the title of this post, since really what you're asking has nothing to do specifically with FITS.

Comment: @Iguananaut that is true, but since I do have FITS files I mentioned them.. If I get specific answers by using FITS instead of ASCII, it would be helpful. I have also tried the answers mentioned, but they don't work

Comment: Regardless what you need to do is get tables into some data structure, and then perform an algorithm on them--the file format the tables were stored in on disk is largely irrelevant for now.

Anyways, it's a little ambiguous what you actually want to get here.  What is the "expected" answer in your example?  1?  3?  What if there are multiple duplicates between table 1 and table2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very nearly there. All you need is a `Counter` to count how many times each row appears in the second file.

```
from collections import Counter
# Create frequency table of (C,D) column pairs
file2freq = Counter(zip(C,D))
# Look up frequency value for each row of file 1
for a,b in zip(A,B):
    # and print out the row and frequency data.
    print a,b,file2freq[a,b]
```

and that's it! Just four really simple lines of code.

If you don't have `collections.Counter`, you may use `defaultdict` to simulate it:

```
from collections import defaultdict
file2freq = defaultdict(int)
for c,d in zip(C,D):
    file2freq[c,d] += 1
for a,b in zip(A,B):
    print a,b,file2freq[a,b]
```

Comment: I would like to know how file2freq with the `[]` did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

1. Load the file 1 rows in a dictionary, in which each row load as a key with 0 value.
2. Iterate on file 2, and if the row match a key in the previous dictionary, add one to that key
3. Display the dictionary results

Comment: Could you if possible explain with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this will help. See the comments to understand.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

A = np.array([1,1,2,4])
B = np.array([2,3,4,5])

C = np.array([1,1,1,1,2,1,1])
D = np.array([2,2,2,3,4,4,3])

dict1 = Counter(zip(C,D)) # made a dictionary of occurrences of results of zipping C an D 

#print dict1 #just uncomment this line to understand what Counter do.
print("A    B : Rowcount")
for i in zip(A,B):
    print (str(i[0]) + "    " + str(i[1]) + " : " + str(dict1[i]))
```

Output:

```
A    B : Rowcount
1    2 : 3
1    3 : 2
2    4 : 1
4    5 : 0
```

Comment: I have a FITS file, so my rows are read easily and are numpy arrays. Could you explain what dict1 does? So if I have columns `A,B,C,D` as numpy arrays how should I proceed?

Comment: They are FITS files, so each column can be read easily unlike a txt file. So my columns are numpy arrays, can also be converted to whichever format if you want.

Comment: Well, it is like a normal text ASCII file.. not anything complicated.. It looks the same. As I said, my columns are now numpy arrays, I can say `print A` and it will print all the entries in column A

Comment: So, you want to compare now two numpy arrays A and B with C and D respectively, i.e., row1 of A to row1 of C and row1 of B to row1 of D and then for row2  and so on.  Am I right ?!

Comment: @ThePredator see the edited code now. Probably now fit to your need. :)

Comment: Your solution gives me back rows A and B and not the number counts I wanted :(

Comment: @ThePredator The number after the `:` symbol is count of the each row. Is it not printing?! The code is OK. I double checked it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59761/discussion-between-thepredator-and-tanmaya-meher).

Answer (score 0):

Pandas might be useful for this sort of thing.  This example constructs two Pandas `DataFrame`s from scratch, but it should be possible to wrap the FITS tables in `DataFrame`s (I think that would be a separate question though).  To use the example from your post:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> table1 = pandas.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2], 'B': [2, 3, 4]})
>>> table2 = pandas.DataFrame({'C': [1, 1, 1], 'D': [2, 2, 2]})
>>> table1
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  2  4
>>> table2
   C  D
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  1  2
```

Now there's a few ways you could go about this.  The problem as stated is slightly ambiguous, actually.  Do you want *all* the rows in table2 that have a match in table1?  Or could you exclude duplicates from table2?  You could do something like this:

```
>>> m = pandas.merge(table1, table2, left_on=('A', 'B'), right_on=('C', 'D'), how='inner')
>>> m
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  1  2
1  1  2  1  2
2  1  2  1  2
>>> m.drop_duplicates()
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  1  2
```

Basically this will give you all rows that are common between the two tables.

Comment: All I want to do is take the `first row of table 1`, find out `how many rows of table 2 are similar` and count them. Do the same for row 2, find out how many similar rows are there in table 2 and count them. All `these counts I need to store as the 3rd column` in my first table. P.S. My second table has items in order, i.e. the similar value rows are all not randomly sorted, they are in order.

Comment: That's all stuff that should be clarified in the original question.  It might help also to explain the purpose of this less abstractly--what the data is, etc.  

So for each row in in table 1 you want a count of all matching rows in table 2 (of which there may be duplicates)?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want. For each row in table 1, a count of all matching rows in table 2. I think I have mentioned that in the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
def read_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    return data


def parse_data(data):
    parsed_data = []
    for line in data.split('\n'):
        line_striped = line.strip()  # remove spaces on left and right site
        try:
            left, right = line_striped.split(' ', 1)  # split on first space
        except ValueError:
            continue
        right = right.strip()  # remove spaces on left site from right
        parsed_data.append((left, right))
    return parsed_data


f1_data = read_from_file("file1.txt")
f2_data = read_from_file("file2.txt")
f1_pdata = parse_data(f1_data)
f2_pdata = parse_data(f2_data)

# compare
for f2_item in f2_pdata:
    for f1_item in f1_pdata:
        if f2_item == f1_item:
            print f2_item, "occures in file2 and file1"
```

Comment: I have a FITS file, so I don't need to load my data using the `def` functions. I would like to know what your #compare code does. What is `f2_item`?

Comment: As you wrote in an other comment it's an ASCII file. Therefore no need to use a third party python module to compare the lines.

Comment: My "compare" is quite ugly, but will work. It compares each line of file1 with each line of file2. So if file1 has a length of m and file2 has a length of n the runtime will be O(m*n).

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer the OP's question.