# Counting the weighted intersection of equivalent rows in two tables

Tags: python, algorithm, list, matching

The following question is a generalization to the question posted here:

[Counting the intersection of equivalent rows in two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428577/counting-the-intersection-of-equivalent-rows-in-two-tables)

I have two FITS files. For example, **the first file has 100 rows and 2 columns. The second file has 1000 rows and 3 columns**.

`FITS FILE 1          FITS FILE 2`

```
A        B        C        D     E 

1        2        1        2    0.1
1        3        1        2    0.3 
2        4        1        2    0.9
```

I need to take the first row of the first file, i.e 1 and 2 and check how many rows in the second file have C = 1 and D = 2 **weighting each pair (C,D) with respect to the corresponding value in column E**.

In the example, I have 3 rows in the second file that have C = 1 and D = 2. They have weights E = 0.1, 0.3, and 0.9, respectively. Weighting with respect to the values in E, I need to associate the value 0.1+0.3+0.9 = 1.3 to the pair (A,B) = (1,2) of the first file. Then, I need to do the same for the second row (first file), i.e 1 and 3 and find out how many rows in the second file have 1 and 3, again weighting with respect to the value in column E, and so on.

**The first file does not have duplicates (all the rows have different pairs, none are identical, only file 2 has many identical pairs which I need to find)**.

I finally need the **weighted numbers** of rows in the second file that have the similar values as that of the rows of the first FITS file.

The result should be:

`A    B    Number 
1    2      1.3   # 1 and 2 occurs 1.3 times
1    3      4.5   # 1 and 3 occurs 4.5 times`

and so on for all pairs in A and B columns.

**I know from the post cited above that the solution for weights in column E all equal to 1 involves  `Counter`**, as follows:

```
from collections import Counter
# Create frequency table of (C,D) column pairs
file2freq = Counter(zip(C,D))
# Look up frequency value for each row of file 1
for a,b in zip(A,B):
    # and print out the row and frequency data.
    print a,b,file2freq[a,b]
```

**To answer the question I need to include the weights in E when I use `Counter`:**

```
file2freq = Counter(zip(C,D))
```

I was wondering if it is possible to do that.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd follow up on the suggestion made by Iguananaut in the comments to that question. I believe `numpy` is an ideal tool for this.

```
import numpy as np

fits1 = np.genfromtxt('fits1.csv')
fits2 = np.genfromtxt('fits2.csv')

summed = np.zeros(fits1.shape[0])
for ind, row in enumerate(fits1):
    condition = (fits2[:,:2] == row).all(axis=1)
    summed[ind] = fits2[condition,-1].sum()  # change the assignment operator to += if the rows in fits1 are not unique
```

After the import, the first 2 lines will load the data from the files. That will return an array of floats, which comes with the warning: comparing one float to another is prone to bugs. In this case it will work though, because both the columns in `fits1.csv` and the first 2 columns in `fits2.csv` are integers and parsed in the same manner by `genfromtxt`.

Then, in the for-loop the variable `condition` is created, which states that anytime the first two columns in `fits2` match with the columns of the current `row` of `fits1`, it is to be taken into account (the result is a boolean array).
Then, finally, for the current row index `ind`, set the value of the array `summed` to the sum of all the values in column 3 of `fits2`, where the `condition` was `True`.

For a mini example I made, I got this:

```
oliver@armstrong:/tmp/sto$ cat fits1.csv
1   2
1   3
2   4
oliver@armstrong:/tmp/sto$ cat fits2.csv
1   2   .1
1   2   .3
1   2   .9
2   4   .3
1   5   .5
2   4   .7
# run the above code:
# summed is:
# array([ 1.3,  0. ,  1. ])
```